# Exploring MITM -> SSL / TLS, certificates and proxy capabilities

Tags: ios, node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, charles-proxy

I haven an iOS application that communicates with an API over https. I've successfully intercepted these messages in clear text in Charles proxy by installing Charles proxy's root certificate on my phone and set my computer as proxy.

I'm now trying to wrap my head around how all this work, so I'm trying to reproduce the functionality of Charles proxy in NodeJS.

**Steps I've taken:**

1. Generate root CA and install in iOS
2. Generate server certificate matching the APIs server certificate, signed with the CA from step 1
3. Setup NodeJS server with the server certificate

Now, if I set my computer as proxy in IOS, go into the iOS application, then shouldn't I get the requests to my NodeJS server? Nothing is really happening. The NodeJS server isn't receiving any requests and the iOS application fail to display information (because it can't reach the API of course).

**In my head, the following flow should occur:**

- iOS application establish connection with NodeJS application by asking for server certificate
- NodeJS returns the server certificate falsly saying that it is the actual API the iOS app is trying to communicate with
- iOS app checks its CA store and finds the CA from step 1 and falsly verifies that the server is correct
- iOS app should now be able to communicate with the NodeJS server and the NodeJS server should be able to intercept the messages in clear text

**My question is:** What am I missing? Why does it not work?

I've included some code below. Note that I haven't begun proxying to the "real" API yet, I'm just trying to receive the messages in NodeJS.

**Below is code related to the steps above:**

1. Generate root CA and server certificate

   ```
   # CA
   openssl genrsa -out ca.key 4096
   openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out ca.crt
   ```
2. Generate server certificate matching the APIs server certificate, signed with the CA from step 1

   ```
   # Server
   openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
   openssl req -new -sha256 -key server.key -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=MyOrg Inc./CN=external.api.com" -out server.csr
   openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 500 -sha256
   ```
3. NodeJS server

   ```
   const fs = require('fs');
   const https = require('https');

   const options = {
     key: fs.readFileSync('./server.key'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt'),
   };

   https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
     console.log(`Got request headers: ${JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2)}`);
     console.log(`Got request body: ${JSON.stringify(req.body, true, 2)}`);
     console.log(`Got request url: ${req.url}`);

     res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/plain' });
     res.write('yup');
     res.end();
   }).listen(3102);
   ```

Comment: Why have you chosen to listen on port 3102? Is the client connecting to your service on that port? Test from a different system using `curl` or `wget`.

Comment: Just random port. Yes, iOS is configured to proxy to the computer on this port. I can reach the server from any other client - browser, curl, wget. So the server is up and running but iOS doesn't seem to proxy to it correctly.